# How do you include time_t on an Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, ctime

I am trying to compile and upload one of the example WiFly projects to my Arduino.  One of the example's functions is has return-type 'time_t', but the compiler doesn't recognize that. I have tried including both `<ctime>` and `<time.h>`.

This is my first time really using C++, So how do I import 'time_t' on my Arduino?

Comment: well, the Arduino Time.h header  definitely defines time_t.  I think it's time to show the exact error message, and some sample code. try `#include <Time.h>; time_t Foo;` and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you'll need to do two things to use `time_t` on your Arduino.

1. [Download the Time Library](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/time)
2. Include `<Time.h>` (note the capital T)

Comment: An earlier google search brought me to those and I tried both of them.  Neither worked.

Comment: @KeeganMcCarthy: interesting, it appears they named it `<Time.h>` with a capital T.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the Time library it gets a .zip file that has 3 folders. TimeAlarms, Time and DS1307RTC. Try moving these 3 folders out of the Time folder, and directly into the libraries folder.

See the comment on November 14, 2012 at 5:09 http://adventuresinarduinoland.blogspot.com/2012/09/yet-another-real-time-clock.html